# PCI - Backend Applications and SQL Injection

Tags: sql-injection, pci-dss

Currently pursuing PCI certification and our internal team is mandating that all inline SQL be moved to parameterized queries. No question this makes sense for web applications.

I'm wondering about opinions on the applicability of this for backend applications. We have a number of very old (VB6) applications used to integrate with various other organizations (think ETL jobs with batch file exchanges over SFTP). Updating all these is a tremendous task and I'm wondering how necessary it would actually be.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You have to consider insider threats, if these applications have sql injection vulnerabilities and access to sensitive data you could be opening yourself to unauthorised viewing and modification of your data by malicious internal actors.  The rule is is never trust input, even if it does come from someone that works for you.

Secondly, think defence in depth. What if an attacker breaches your perimiter and finds one of these tools. This could be an additional attack vector.

I would pen test these applications for sqli vulnerabilities and fix issues you discover rather than a blanket rewrite, that would be more efficient.

Comment: I think a code review *may* be more efficient, if you have source control and can search for the code that generates/sends SQL queries, it's probably worth doing so, if you only find a few instances then it would be more efficient to fix them all, rather than pen testing.  (if you find thousands, then maybe not!)

Comment: Good point. A static analysis tool could make swift work of this.